# always getting 0.00 when try to calculating execution time in C

Tags: c, time, clock

hey there i'm trying to calculate execution time of a simple multithreaded programme on UBUNTU. despite of i researched and used various methods, i always get 0.0000 value. here is my simple code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

clock_t startm, stopm;
#define START if ( (startm = clock()) == -1) {printf("Error calling clock");exit(1);}
#define STOP if ( (stopm = clock()) == -1) {printf("Error calling clock");exit(1);}
#define PRINTTIME printf( "%6.9f seconds used by the processor.\n", ((double)stopm-startm)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

void* thread_function(int);
void function();

int total=0;
int counter;

pthread_mutex_t mutex1=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    START
    counter = atoi(argv[1]);
    function();
    STOP
    PRINTTIME
    return;
}

void function(){
    int i;

    pthread_t t_array[counter];

    for(i=0; i<counter; i++){
        pthread_create(&t_array[i], NULL, thread_function, i);
    }

    for(i=0; i<counter; i++){
        pthread_join(t_array[i],NULL);
    }
    printf("Total = %d\n", total);
}

void* thread_function(int index){

   pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );

   printf("Index : %d\n", index);
   total++;
   usleep(100000);

   pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );

}
```

i will appreciate if you can help and thanks anyway.

Comment: why not use the build-in function "time"? just call your program with `time ./myProgram`. No need to code anything

Comment: actually this is just shortened part of code. i have to take that value as double to print on screen in proper way. is there a way to do that_?

Comment: I don't understand: Do you have to calculate something with the time? calling `time ./foo` prints the elapsed time on the screen. What do you mean by "in a proper way"?

Comment: `clock()` measures CPU time, `usleep` doesn't use CPU time, so your programme actually spends almost no time at all on the CPU.

Comment: @DanielFischer: As a matter of fact, clock measures thin air. It is no use for anything.

Comment: @Vlad, that's a bit harsh, I think. If your code actually does some work for a not too short time, you can use it to get a rough idea of how long it takes. At least, one could on all systems I tried it on. It's coarse, but it can detect the difference between 1 second and 1.5 just fine, usually.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Well, for a very non-precise measurement in units that don't really relate to anything, maybe it is fine. Though I don't see any good reason to use it.

Comment: @Vlad, hypothetically, a scenario where nothing better is available could be constructed. Realistically, however, every platform I have even a passing acquaintance with offers something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to time a function in code.  Consider gettimeofday()

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double now(void)
{
   struct timeval tv;
   double retval=0;
   gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
   retval=tv.tv_usec;
   retval+= (double)tv.tv_usecs / 1000000.;
   return retval;
}

int main()
{
   double start=now();
   // run code here
   printf("elapsed time = %.6f"\n", now() - start);
   return 0;

}|
```

Comment: POSIX.1-2008  marks  gettimeofday()  as  obsolete, recommending the use of clock_gettime(2) instead.

Comment: yeah i was hoping to use time calculation in a function and this works great! thanks for your reply :)